# Multiple non-grouped items in R tabular() output

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that I want to use `tables::tabular()` to setup for nice printing in latex. It has 5 repeated items in two groups (`normal` and `compress`), where I want three items to not be grouped, and then the rest to be grouped.

```
test_table <- structure(list(id = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("GO:0005525", "GO:0005634", "GO:0008270", 
"GO:0019001", "GO:0046914"), class = "factor"), description = c("nucleus", 
"zinc ion binding", "transition metal ion binding", "GTP binding", 
"guanyl nucleotide binding", "nucleus", "zinc ion binding", "transition metal ion binding", 
"GTP binding", "guanyl nucleotide binding"), IPR.group = c("H", 
"W", "W", "AE", "AE", "H", "W", "W", "AE", "AE"), consistent = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), p = c(4.92245771293119e-05, 
1.08157386873641e-21, 2.06049782601929e-14, 0.999999999562468, 
0.999999999985399, 1, 1, 0.999999999999996, 6.51428091733489e-09, 
2.3200965815753e-10), padjust = c(0.0166308749872604, 8.52640733187206e-19, 
1.2182693396339e-11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9.06251433499824e-07, 3.91930601101827e-08
), metal = c("zn", "zn", "zn", "mg", "mg", "ca", "ca", "ca", 
"ca", "ca"), perc = c(0.841726618705036, 0.831807780320366, 0.519281914893617, 
0.875598086124402, 0.876651982378855, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sig = c("TRUE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", 
"TRUE", "TRUE"), which = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("compress", "normal"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"description", "IPR.group", "consistent", "p", "padjust", "metal", 
"perc", "sig", "which"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

test_table
           id                  description IPR.group consistent            p      padjust metal      perc   sig    which
1  GO:0005634                      nucleus         H       TRUE 4.922458e-05 1.663087e-02    zn 0.8417266  TRUE   normal
2  GO:0008270             zinc ion binding         W       TRUE 1.081574e-21 8.526407e-19    zn 0.8318078  TRUE   normal
3  GO:0046914 transition metal ion binding         W       TRUE 2.060498e-14 1.218269e-11    zn 0.5192819  TRUE   normal
4  GO:0005525                  GTP binding        AE       TRUE 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    mg 0.8755981 FALSE   normal
5  GO:0019001    guanyl nucleotide binding        AE       TRUE 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    mg 0.8766520 FALSE   normal
6  GO:0005634                      nucleus         H       TRUE 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    ca 0.0000000 FALSE compress
7  GO:0008270             zinc ion binding         W       TRUE 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    ca 0.0000000 FALSE compress
8  GO:0046914 transition metal ion binding         W       TRUE 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    ca 0.0000000 FALSE compress
9  GO:0005525                  GTP binding        AE       TRUE 6.514281e-09 9.062514e-07    ca 0.0000000  TRUE compress
10 GO:0019001    guanyl nucleotide binding        AE       TRUE 2.320097e-10 3.919306e-08    ca 0.0000000  TRUE compress
```

So, I can start to get close if I do:

```
library(tables)
tabular(id ~ which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)




    which                                                                      
            compress                             normal                                
 id         p         padjust   metal perc sig   p         padjust   metal perc   sig  
 GO:0005525 6.514e-09 9.063e-07 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8756 FALSE
 GO:0005634 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 4.922e-05 1.663e-02 zn    0.8417 TRUE 
 GO:0008270 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 1.082e-21 8.526e-19 zn    0.8318 TRUE 
 GO:0019001 2.320e-10 3.919e-08 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8767 FALSE
 GO:0046914 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 2.060e-14 1.218e-11 zn    0.5193 TRUE
```

But, as soon as I try to add the `description` column anywhere I think
it should be, I start to get errors:

```
tabular((id + description) ~ which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)
# Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : Duplicate values: description and p

tabular((id + IPR.group) ~ which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)
# Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : Duplicate values: IPR.group and p
```

Even putting `description` in the independent side returns something really funny where the character gets turned into a numeric:

```
tabular(id ~ description + which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)
                        which                                                                      
                        compress                             normal                                
 id         description p         padjust   metal perc sig   p         padjust   metal perc   sig  
 GO:0005525 2           6.514e-09 9.063e-07 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8756 FALSE
 GO:0005634 2           1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 4.922e-05 1.663e-02 zn    0.8417 TRUE 
 GO:0008270 2           1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 1.082e-21 8.526e-19 zn    0.8318 TRUE 
 GO:0019001 2           2.320e-10 3.919e-08 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8767 FALSE
 GO:0046914 2           1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 2.060e-14 1.218e-11 zn    0.5193 TRUE
```

I can fudge it if I make a new column that is the concatenation of the
columns I want displayed, but I'd have to write something to make them all look consistent:

```
test_table$ID <- paste0(test_table$id, " ", test_table$description, " ", test_table$IPR.group)
test_table$ID <- factor(test_table$ID)
tabular(ID ~ which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)


                                           which                                                                      
                                           compress                             normal                                
 ID                                        p         padjust   metal perc sig   p         padjust   metal perc   sig  
 GO:0005525 GTP binding AE                 6.514e-09 9.063e-07 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8756 FALSE
 GO:0005634 nucleus H                      1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 4.922e-05 1.663e-02 zn    0.8417 TRUE 
 GO:0008270 zinc ion binding W             1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 1.082e-21 8.526e-19 zn    0.8318 TRUE 
 GO:0019001 guanyl nucleotide binding AE   2.320e-10 3.919e-08 ca    0    TRUE  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8767 FALSE
 GO:0046914 transition metal ion binding W 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE 2.060e-14 1.218e-11 zn    0.5193 TRUE
```

I thought I should be able to do it using 1 of the other solutions above, but not so much. Any help would be appreciated. Also, any solutions should also remove the `which` that is shown above `compress` and `normal` in the header of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems close, at least:

```
> tabular(id ~ Heading()*which*(description + p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)

            compress                                                         
 id         description                  p         padjust   metal perc sig  
 GO:0005525 GTP binding                  6.514e-09 9.063e-07 ca    0    TRUE 
 GO:0005634 nucleus                      1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE
 GO:0008270 zinc ion binding             1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE
 GO:0019001 guanyl nucleotide binding    2.320e-10 3.919e-08 ca    0    TRUE 
 GO:0046914 transition metal ion binding 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE

 normal                                                             
 description                  p         padjust   metal perc   sig  
 GTP binding                  1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8756 FALSE
 nucleus                      4.922e-05 1.663e-02 zn    0.8417 TRUE 
 zinc ion binding             1.082e-21 8.526e-19 zn    0.8318 TRUE 
 guanyl nucleotide binding    1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8767 FALSE
 transition metal ion binding 2.060e-14 1.218e-11 zn    0.5193 TRUE
```

...but you may not be happy with the duplication of the `description` column in each `which` group. There might be a way to fix that by pulling the `description` term outside of the parens, but it looks like that will require some other magical incantation as the naive change complains with an error about duplicate values in combination with `p` it seems.

Edit: So close to the magic incantation...

```
tabular(id ~ (description*Heading()*min)+Heading()*which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)
```

This looks right (maybe?). Issue appears to be `tabular` really want to apply a summary function to `description`. `unique()` would probably be a better choice of "dummy" summary function than `min()` in this case I suppose, and seems to give the same result.

Edit: Latest refinement...

```
> tabular(id ~ (description*Heading()*unique)+Heading()*which*(p + padjust + metal + perc + sig)*Heading()*identity, data = test_table)

                                         compress                            
 id         description                  p         padjust   metal perc sig  
 GO:0005525 GTP binding                  6.514e-09 9.063e-07 ca    0    TRUE 
 GO:0005634 nucleus                      1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE
 GO:0008270 zinc ion binding             1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE
 GO:0019001 guanyl nucleotide binding    2.320e-10 3.919e-08 ca    0    TRUE 
 GO:0046914 transition metal ion binding 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 ca    0    FALSE

 normal                                
 p         padjust   metal perc   sig  
 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8756 FALSE
 4.922e-05 1.663e-02 zn    0.8417 TRUE 
 1.082e-21 8.526e-19 zn    0.8318 TRUE 
 1.000e+00 1.000e+00 mg    0.8767 FALSE
 2.060e-14 1.218e-11 zn    0.5193 TRUE
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I want description separate from the others

Comment: @rmflight You mean pulled out of the `compress` and `normal` groupings entirely, then?

Comment: Yes @joran, I want it out like `id`

Comment: @rmflight Try my latest edit. Feels like a hack, but I think it might actually be the right output.

Comment: yep, it works. Might be hackish, but it gives the right output. Thanks @joran!